# Fedora 35 - DisplayLink - USB 3 in 2xDVI out - WIll it work?

Tags: usb, fedora, dvi

I have an Dell Inspiron 3780.  This is a really nice laptop, and runs Fedora 35 beautifully.  I wish to attach 2x Samsung 2333T monitors via their DVI-D interface.

I have read that an HDMI to DVI splitter can only really mirror to two separate monitors, which is not the desired result.  I wish to have an extended workspace across both monitors so they can be used as a single monitor.

I have also discovered that DisplayLink via USB might be able to solve my problem, but, of course, I then will require more expensive hardware.  It looks like this product might be able to solve my problem : [Targus 4k Universal Docking Station](https://www.targus.com/za/4k-universal-docking-station-dock130euz).

So, that would mean I would require the DisplayLink driver to be installed into my F35 instance.

Am I analyzing this correctly.  I don't want to shell out loads of money if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with a fujitsu PR8.1  This device has a DVI-D and a DisplayPort graphics connection, so, all I needed was a DisplayPort to DVI adapter, and everything works absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for this device to work, you must have functioning displayport in the system os.

The linked Targus does not appear to offer linux support or installation instructions, that might mean it is difficult or impossible with standard repositories.

Displayport installation may be possible through the https://negativo17.org/multimedia/ repository, but it's quite a gamble with the linked device as they show no support for any linux distro.

Comment: Do you mean DisplayLink (not DisplayPort) ?